# postgisQueryBuilder in QGIS can't connect to PostgreSQL DB - QPSQL driver not loaded

Tags: qgis, postgresql, database

PostgreSQL is installed properly and I can work with my DB very well. My databases show up as connected inside the QGIS browser window. I think the appropriate packages are installed:

```
# rpm -qa post* libqt*
postgresql9.6-contrib-9.6.15-1.mga6
postgresql9.6-9.6.15-1.mga6
postgis-2.2.2-3.mga6
postgresql-jdbc-9.4.1210-1.mga6
libqt4-database-plugin-sqlite-4.8.7-15.1.mga6
postgresql9.6-plpgsql-9.6.15-1.mga6
libqtsql4-4.8.7-15.1.mga6
postgresql9.6-server-9.6.15-1.mga6
libqt4-database-plugin-pgsql-4.8.7-15.1.mga6
```

Can someone interpret this stacktrace for me? This is what I get when I try to connect to my DB inside postgisQueryBuilder:

```
Warning: QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
Stacktrace (piped through c++filt):
src/core/qgsmessagelog.cpp: 45: (logMessage) [9835ms] 2019-11-14T17:25:34 Qt[1] QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
qgis[0x40b7c4]
qgis[0x40bafa]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(qt_message_output(QtMsgType, char const*)+0x16)[0x7f46c3634356]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(+0x6f529)[0x7f46c3634529]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(qWarning(char const*, ...)+0x94)[0x7f46c3634774]
/lib64/libQtSql.so.4(+0x14a27)[0x7f46c1ab5a27]
/lib64/libQtSql.so.4(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&)+0x11)[0x7f46c1ab5d41]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSql.so(+0x47c8d)[0x7f4640c65c8d]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8a84)[0x7f4643d039b4]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x667c)[0x7f4643d015ac]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x85c)[0x7f4643d048dc]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x70a6c)[0x7f4643c8ea6c]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f4643c6a8b3]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x5af47)[0x7f4643c78f47]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f4643c6a8b3]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47)[0x7f4643cfa927]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so(+0x13738)[0x7f464380d738]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::invokeSlot(qpycore_slot const&, void**, int)+0x153)[0x7f464351de43]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::unislot(void**)+0x105)[0x7f464351dc1f]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)+0x8a)[0x7f464351db02]
Warning: QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
Stacktrace (piped through c++filt):
src/core/qgsmessagelog.cpp: 45: (logMessage) [6ms] 2019-11-14T17:25:34 Qt[1] QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE
Driver not loaded Driver not loaded
qgis[0x40b7c4]
qgis[0x40bafa]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(qt_message_output(QtMsgType, char const*)+0x16)[0x7f46c3634356]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(+0x6f529)[0x7f46c3634529]
/lib64/libQtCore.so.4(qWarning(char const*, ...)+0x94)[0x7f46c3634774]
/lib64/libQtSql.so.4(+0x14aad)[0x7f46c1ab5aad]
/lib64/libQtSql.so.4(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(QString const&, QString const&)+0x11)[0x7f46c1ab5d41]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSql.so(+0x47c8d)[0x7f4640c65c8d]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x8a84)[0x7f4643d039b4]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x667c)[0x7f4643d015ac]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x85c)[0x7f4643d048dc]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x70a6c)[0x7f4643c8ea6c]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f4643c6a8b3]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(+0x5af47)[0x7f4643c78f47]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x43)[0x7f4643c6a8b3]
/lib64/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords+0x47)[0x7f4643cfa927]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sip.so(+0x13738)[0x7f464380d738]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::invokeSlot(qpycore_slot const&, void**, int)+0x153)[0x7f464351de43]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::unislot(void**)+0x105)[0x7f464351dc1f]
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so(PyQtProxy::qt_metacall(QMetaObject::Call, int, void**)+0x8a)[0x7f464351db02]
```

Do I somehow have to load that QPSQL driver before? Or do you see hints about missing packages inside this? I'm relatively new to this.